# Texture only compiling sometimes using color[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm trying to use this loop to fill the color array which I then use to set pixels but for some reason I can't fathom it's only working some of the time. sometimes it produces the texture perfectly, other times its a mess of mixed up lines, what am I doing wrong?

```
void texRend()
{
    GameObject parentGameObject = new GameObject("SpaceStation");

    int tileRow = 0;
    int tileCol = 0;

    GameObject floorQuad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);

    floorQuad.transform.localScale = new Vector3(stationWidth*1.28f,stationHeight*1.28f,1);
    floorQuad.transform.parent = parentGameObject.transform;
    floorQuad.transform.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    Color transparent = new Color(0,0,0,0);

    Texture2D floorTex = new Texture2D(stationWidth*256, stationHeight*256, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    Color[] floorArray = new Color[stationWidth*256*stationHeight*256];

    int k = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < stationWidth*256; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < stationHeight*256; col++)
        {
            tileRow = Mathf.FloorToInt(row/256);
            tileCol = Mathf.FloorToInt(col/256);

            float prow = ((float)tileRow/(float)stationWidth)*scale;
            float pcol = ((float)tileCol/(float)stationHeight)*scale;

            if(roomType[tileRow, tileCol] != (int)room.None && roomType[tileRow, tileCol] != (int)room.Corridor)
            {
                int tileNumber = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.PerlinNoise(prow,pcol)*baseSprites.Length)%baseSprites.Length);
                floorArray[k] = baseSprites[tileNumber].texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
            }
            else if(roomType[tileRow, tileCol] == (int)room.Corridor)
            {
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.NESW)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorNESW.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.NS)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorNS.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.EW)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorEW.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.NE)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorNE.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.NW)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorNW.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.SE)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorSE.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.SW)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorSW.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.WNE)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorWNE.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.NES)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorNES.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.ESW)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorESW.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
                if(connections[tileRow,tileCol] == (int)connect.SWN)
                {
                    floorArray[k] = corridorFloorSWN.texture.GetPixel(row%256, col%256);
                }
            }

            k++;
        }

    }

    floorTex.SetPixels(floorArray);
    floorTex.Apply();
    //attach texture to quad
    floorQuad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = floorTex;
    floorQuad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.shader = Shader.Find("Sprites/Diffuse");

    byte[] bytes = floorTex.EncodeToPNG();
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../floorTexture.png", bytes);

 }
```

OK, after running this a load of times it seems it only produces correct textures when the texture is a square. I think I need some kind of dynamic offset.

[image: What it looks like when working]
[image: Not working]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was change around the row and col for loops and it worked perfectly! I wouldn't have expected the texture to turn out wrong in quite that way having those incorrectly.